# How to create a new dataframe using specific values in certain columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Edit: Adding a reproducible dataframe as per request. Also, it isn't necessary to have A,B in the index.

```py
data = {'ID':['A','B','A','A','B','B','A','A'],
        'Property':['x','x','y','x','y','y','x','y']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Original question-
for example, I want to convert the dataframe below

```
index    col_1    col_2
0          A        x
1          A        y
2          B        y
3          A        y
.
.
.
.
n          B        x
n+1        A        x
```

to

```
index    x    y
A       54   23
B       61   25
```

Basically count the occurrences of x and y in the above dataframe and make a new dataframe as shown below.

Comment: kindly share a reproducible dataframe that can be used to solve your challenge.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You need to demonstrate that you have made an attempt to solve this problem on your own.  Provide whatever code you have come up with.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
df.value_counts().unstack()
```

---

Docs:

- [`pandas.DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly. Appreciate the answer and the references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df["col_1"], df["col_2"])
```

Comment: Nice!  Fix your col_1 name so OP doesn't get an error.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. This worked perfectly! This and the answer by @Pablo C gave the same correct output that I was looking for.

Comment: @forever_noob Yes, both will produce the same results.